# PIL 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: utf-8, python-imaging-library, discord.py, decode, python-unicode

I'm working on pasting two images on top of each other to use as a Discord file for my bot, but whenever I try to feed the finished image data to Discord from PIL and BytesIO, I get this strange error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

This is my code (or the chunk that is relevant):

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(avurl) as second_image:
        image_bytes = await second_image.read()

with Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)).convert("RGB") as first_image:
    output_buffer = BytesIO()
    first_image.save(output_buffer, "png")
    output_buffer.seek(0)

async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get("https://i.imgur.com/dNS0WJO.png") as second_image:
        image_bytes = await second_image.read()

with Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes)) as second_image:
    output_buffer = BytesIO()
    second_image.save(output_buffer, "png")
    output_buffer.seek(0)

first_image.paste(second_image, (0, 0))
buf = io.BytesIO()
first_image.save(buf, "png")
first_image = first_image.getvalue()
buf = buf.getvalue()
file = discord.File(fp=buf, filename="pfp.png")
```